# Switching the editor while editing an article?

Tags: editor

Is it possible to switch the current editor **while** I am editing an article? I have tried [`switch-editor`](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/switch-editor) and that works nice, but when I use it while I am editing an article, then I still need to close and reopen the article for the switch to take effect.

I am looking for a solution that allows me switching while I am in the edit view of an article.

Comment: Out of interest, why would you want to do this. Can you simply not choose you preferred editor, then stick with it?

Comment: I mostly use TinyMCE or I directly edit the HTML, but the HTML editor that comes with TinyMCE is not very good, no syntax highlighting, no pretty printing, etc. so I would like to be able to switch between TinyMCE and Codemirror on the fly. Especially when I need to create grid layouts this is not possible TinyMCE and I need to write HTML directly.

Comment: You can also add a TinyMCE plugin that adds a code edit function directly to the TinyMCE. Easiest way is to use JCE, which is a version of the TinyMCE with extra plugins including the one you want. Alternately http://www.byman.it/site/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=213:tinymce-source-colored&catid=39&Itemid=154 but I haven't tried that myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's simply syntax highlighting and pretty print for HTML, then Codemirror would be best for you.

If did find a plugin called [Editor Switcher](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/editor-switcher) than allows you to switch whilst editing.

Once installed, enable the plugin. Then go to your Joomla Global Configuration and set the default editor to Editor Switcher.

Note, that before switching, please save your changes as it refreshes the page. By default, it will come up with a confirmation.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes this plugin seems to do a better job then the switch-editor plugin I found. Its styling could be improved a bit, but functionality wise it does the job.

Comment: +1 for Editor Switcher. I use it all the time, for the same reasons @lanoxx mention. Excellent extension, and a real time saver.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I usually prefer to use JCE. No need to mention other advantages of it, but in regards with your question it provides 2 useful features:

First of all it's code editor is pretty good - with syntax highlighting and code indentation.

Nevertheless, it also provides a toggle editor state, and you easily switch on/off the editor whenever you need it.